# How to get dictionary values as a generic list, when each entry's value is a list

Tags: c#, list, dictionary

I just want get a list from Dictionary values but it's not so simple as it appears !

here the code :

```
Dictionary<string, List<MyType>> myDico = GetDictionary();
List<MyType> items = ???
```

I try :

```
List<MyType> items = new List<MyType>(myDico.values)
```

But it does not work :-(

Comment: In what way does it not work?  Are you getting an error?

Comment: The dictionary is a collection of keys mapped to `List<MyType>` objects. So you have multiple `List<MyType>`s in the dictionary. Are you trying to flatten all those lists of `MyType`s into a single one?

Comment: run a loop through the dictionary to populate a items list -- seems pretty straightforward -- i don't know if there's a one step way of doing it though.

Answer (score 79, accepted):

Off course, myDico.Values is `List<List<MyType>>`.

Use Linq if you want to flattern your lists

```
var items = myDico.SelectMany (d => d.Value).ToList();
```

Comment: Actually, the type of `Values` would be `Dictionary<string, List<MyType>>.ValueCollection`.

Comment: Does anyone know why it is implemented that way? It makes way more sense to have List<List<MyType>> returned by myDico.Values as it is in Java - or am i missing something?

Answer (score 134):

How about:

```
var values = myDico.Values.ToList();
```

Comment: @J.Chang, this doesn't flattens the values, so with `dic.Values.ToList()` you will gen `List<List<MyType>>` and not a flatten List. This is only valid for a single value on each key.

Answer (score 32):

You probably want to flatten all of the lists in `Values` into a single list:

```
List<MyType> allItems = myDico.Values.SelectMany(c => c).ToList();
```

Answer (score 30):

Another variant:

```
List<MyType> items = new List<MyType>();
items.AddRange(myDico.Values);
```

Comment: Amazing to see how many upvotes you can get without really reading the question. Although you answer the question I had when I came here, the OP actually asked something else (the `Dictionary` contains `List`s).

Comment: @lex82 I rarely ever read the stackoverflow questions.

Comment: Note that [Mathias' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33600671/199364) is a one-line equivalent to this; use Mathias' answer if you have the simple case `Dictionary<MyKeyType, MyType>`, where `MyType` is NOT a List.

Answer (score 20):

My OneLiner:

```
var MyList = new List<MyType>(MyDico.Values);
```

Comment: Worked fine for me!. Thanks.

Comment: This doesn't flatten the lists in the dictionary into one list, I guess.

Comment: Worked for me, Sorry to the folks having worse results. That sucks. I hope one of these others works for you!

Comment: This didn't work until I changed it to var MyList = new List<List<BooBlue>>(dict.Values);

Comment: If `MyType` is NOT a `List<SomeType>`, then this almost worked for me. I had to add `.Cast<MyType>` to convert from `Dictionary<MyKeyType, MyType>.ValueCollection` to `IEnumerable<MyType>`. Use either `var mylist = new List<MyType>(MyDico.Values.Cast<MyType>());`,` or `var mylist = MyDico.Values.Cast<MyType>().To List();`.

Answer (score 4):

Going further on the answer of Slaks, if one or more lists in your dictionary is null, a `System.NullReferenceException` will be thrown when calling `ToList()`, play safe:

```
List<MyType> allItems = myDico.Values.Where(x => x != null).SelectMany(x => x).ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Dictionary<string, MyType> myDico = GetDictionary();

var items = myDico.Select(d=> d.Value).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
List<MyType> items = new List<MyType>()
foreach(var value in myDico.Values)
    items.AddRange(value);
```

The problem is that every key in your dictionary has a list of instances as value. Your code would work, if each key would have exactly one instance as value, as in the following example:

```
Dictionary<string, MyType> myDico = GetDictionary();
List<MyType> items = new List<MyType>(myDico.Values);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        List<String> objListColor = new List<String>() { "Red", "Blue", "Green", "Yellow" };
        List<String> objListDirection = new List<String>() { "East", "West", "North", "South" };

        Dictionary<String, List<String>> objDicRes = new Dictionary<String, List<String>>();
        objDicRes.Add("Color", objListColor);
        objDicRes.Add("Direction", objListDirection);
```

Answer (score 0):

Another variation you could also use

```
MyType[] Temp = new MyType[myDico.Count];
myDico.Values.CopyTo(Temp, 0);
List<MyType> items = Temp.ToList();
```