# Best way to convert a dictionary to list in C#

Tags: c#, linq, list, dictionary

I am having some difficulties to convert a dictionary into a list.

```
var dic = new Dictionary<string, List<Tuple<DateTime, double>>>();
var list = new List<Tuple<DateTime, double>>();
list = dic.ToList(); // Cannot convert...
```

Comment: `dic.Values.ToList()`

Comment: A dictionary is a key-value pair collection, a list is a collection of single elements.   What do you expect the resultant list to look like?

Comment: Actually, I've just realised you have a more fundamental issue in that you have a List within the Dictionary.  What is it you're actually trying to achieve?  It you call ToLIst on the values the result will have to be List<List<Tuple<DateTime, double>>>

Comment: This is also a duplicate (a better one, actually): **[How to get dictionary values as a generic list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7555690/how-to-get-dictionary-values-as-a-generic-list)**

Comment: @Tim I need to get the list part, dateTime and double.

Comment: @DoctorMick I am trying to get the list part = the values and not the keys.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`dict.ToList()` will return collection of `KeyValuePair<string, List<Tuple<DateTime, double>>()`.

If you want to hold all value's collection items in inside one list (flatten values) you need `SelectMany`:

```
list = dict.SelectMany(pair => pair.Value).ToList();
```

Comment: This won't compile, since `SelectMany` assumes, thtat projection returns `IEnumerable<>`

Comment: @Dennis yeah, but in OPs case value type implements `IEnumerable<>`.

Comment: @pwas: you're right, I've missed that.

Comment: @Dennis why you said that it wouldn't compile while for me it works?